# How to show an image with transparent background in Corona

Tags: lua, coronasdk

To load an image in corona i am using following code:

```
local nebula = display.newImage( "download.png" )
nebula.x, nebula.y = display.contentCenterX, display.contentCenterY
```

However if the image has a transparent background it shows something like following:

[image]

If there any way to show just the cloud part? Shouldn't images with transparent background do that automatically?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Actually the images i tried didn't had transparent background. After trying with vector images it was solved. I am not deleting the post as someone might make the same mistake as i did.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like background is not transparent but I'm not sure. Does transparent background is visible as small squares in graphic applications like Paint (on Windows)?

Comment: ldurniat.. you are right. The background wasn't transparent. I downloaded 3-4 image from google searching transparent background, every image had the same issue. After your comment, i tried those in a web page and found out. 

After that tried to load vector images, worked perfectly. Thanks for the help :)